# Why is CorrelationFunction returning a value greater than 1?

Tags: bugs, correlation

OK, I'm getting crazy on this:

```
CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{0.9}, 1], 1]
```

And the output is... 1.071 (!)

The symbolic version

```
CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{a}, 1], 1] // FullSimplify
```

yields the right result $a$.

Am I missing something or is it a bug? Mathematica 13.3.1 on Mac.

**Update**

- I've now filed a bug report.
- As a workaround, for the calculations I'm doing (which are longer then the above minimal example), I first calculate the correlations symbolically and then I substitute the numerical values, but the computation time gets much longer. And, in this case, I don't know if the symbolical results can be trusted either.
- I've just tested this with the newly released version 14.0.0, and the bug has not been resolved yet.

Comment: Confirm it in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Confirmed in v13.3.1 on Win11 (also with `CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{9/10}, 1], 1]` which gives `1071/1000`), but in v11.1.1 in Win10 it returns `0.9`. Actually, in v13.3.1, for some `0.62<a<0.63` it becomes greater than `1`; see `Table[{a, CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{a}, 1], 1]}, {a, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01}] // ListPlot[#, GridLines -> {{}, {1}}] &`: https://imgur.com/a/S9woCYc v11.1.1 However, in Win10 the plot is a straight line $y=x$.

Comment: My guess is that the underlying problem is with `CovarianceFunction` (which I believe is called by `CorrelationFunction`) because `CovarianceFunction[ARProcess[{a}, 1], 1] /. a -> 9/10` gives a different answer than `CovarianceFunction[ARProcess[{9/10}, 1], 1]`.  Namely, `90/19` vs `1071/190`, respectively.

Comment: A workaround `CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{0.9, 0}, 1], 1]`.

Comment: Really weird: 
for any value greater than `a` $\gtrsim$ 0.618034, 
$$ $$
`CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{a}, 1], 1]`
$$ $$
gives a number greater than 1. Also notice 0.618034 ~ `1/GoldenRatio`
$$ $$
plugging in the exact value
$$ $$
 `CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{1/GoldenRatio}, 1], 1] // N`  
$$ $$
returns `0.618034`, while plugging the approximate value 
$$ $$
`CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{0.6180339887498948}, 1], 1]`
$$ $$
yields `1.`

Comment: @ydd: For variable input `a` it returns: `-((a (1 - a^2))/(-1 + a^2))`. For numeric input `a` it returns `-a (-2 + a^2)`. I think the source of the bug may be wrong implementation of `DifferenceRoot`... evaluate `CorrelationFunction[ARProcess[{a, b}, c], d]` to see...